# Getting Multiple Values From Array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

Hope I explain this correctly.

I have in my code

```
$eng[] = "All";
$eng[] = "engine_Sigma";
$eng[] = "engine_K-Series";
$eng[] = "engine_Duratec";
$eng[] = "engine_Suzuki";
$eng[] = "engine_Vauxhall";
$eng[] = "engine_Crossflow";

// query your db
$itemsq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `crm`.`workshop-items` LIMIT 0,100");
$items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemsq);
// do/while? should prob just use a while loop
do {
    $enginetype = explode(":", $items['engineid']);

    foreach ($enginetype as $key) {
        echo "$items[wsiid] - $items[code] - $items[incvat] - $eng[$key] <br>
";
    }

} while ($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemsq));
```

However in the DB the engineid's are stored as 1:3:6 for example or even 1:2:3:4:5:6 now what I want to do is if there are multiple values and they have been split up, 
instead of it just echoing the first item and then echoing the data again for the next id 
(like this WSIID - CODE INCVAT engine_K-Series ) and so on 
I want to do display ( WSIID - CODE - INCVAT - engine_Sigma engine_K-Series )
if $eng is 1 & 3 ( 1:3)

Hope you can understand what I mean

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should echo the first part of the data outside of your `foreach` loop, and echo only the engine type inside the `foreach` :

```
<?php
$eng[] = "All";
$eng[] = "engine_Sigma";
$eng[] = "engine_K-Series";
$eng[] = "engine_Duratec";
$eng[] = "engine_Suzuki";
$eng[] = "engine_Vauxhall";
$eng[] = "engine_Crossflow";

// query your db
$itemsq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `crm`.`workshop-items` LIMIT 0,100");
//$items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemsq); # you should delete this, see my explanation below
// do/while? should prob just use a while loop
do {
    $enginetype = explode(":", $items['engineid']);

    echo "$items[wsiid] - $items[code] - $items[incvat] - ";
    foreach ($enginetype as $key) {
       echo "$eng[$key] ";
    }
    echo "<br />";

} while ($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemsq));
```

You should delete your first execution of `$items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemsq);`, or your `do...while` loop will start at the 2nd iteration.

Comment: Try a `while` instead of a `do... while`, the former executes the loop  after checking the condition, whereas the latter executes the loop, then checks the condition. Hence, if there's no result from your query, `do...while` will still execute the loop once.

Comment: just changed to 

     while ($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemsq)) {
    $enginetype = explode(":", $items['engineid']);

    echo "$items[wsiid] - $items[code] - $items[incvat] - ";
    foreach ($enginetype as $key) {
       echo "$eng[$key] ";
    }
    echo "<br />";

} ;

Works great now ! Thanks roberto !

Comment: how can i assign all relevant values from $eng[$key] to a variable eg $test 
so that all values will be displayed when I echo $test ?